# Rewrite SQL script without repeating same nested queries

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, subquery

I have *@a*, *@b*, *@c* and *@d* variables declared.

How can I rewrite the following code without creating the same nested queries several times?

```
SELECT @a, @b, COUNT(DISTINCT id)
FROM Table t
WHERE @a IN
        (SELECT col FROM Table
        WHERE id = t.id)
AND @b IN
        (SELECT col FROM Table
        WHERE id = t.id)
AND @c NOT IN
        (SELECT col FROM Table
        WHERE id = t.id)
AND @d NOT IN
        (SELECT col FROM Table
        WHERE id = t.id)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a conditional aggregation approach

```
SELECT @a, @b,COUNT(id)
FROM   (SELECT id
        FROM   [Table]
        GROUP  BY id
        HAVING MAX(CASE WHEN col = @a THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 1 AND 
               MAX(CASE WHEN col = @b THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 1 AND
               MAX(CASE WHEN col = @c THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0 AND
               MAX(CASE WHEN col = @d THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0
                ) T
```